# Multiple patterns and replacements from "dictionary" dataframe in R, maybe with gsub?

Tags: r, gsub, string-substitution

I have a dataset with strings (data$text) containing names of emojis instead of actual images (e.g., `FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY`). Now I'm trying to replace each emoji name with the actual emoji. The names and emojis are saved in an extra dataset which works as "dictionary" (`emojis$name` and `emojis$emoji`).

So this is my dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(text = c("blabla HUGGING_FACE PARTY_POPPER", "bla FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY bla FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY", "PARTY_POPPER")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

looking like:

```
                                                   text
1                      blabla HUGGING_FACE PARTY_POPPER
2 bla FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY bla FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY
3                                          PARTY_POPPER
```

Note that the emoji names are just part of the text. The rest oft the text should remain.

And this is my "dictionary":

```
emojis <- structure(list(name = c("FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY", "HUGGING_FACE", 
                                  "PARTY_POPPER"), emoji = c("\U0001f602", "\U0001f917", "\U0001f389"
                                  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

looking like:

```
                    name      emoji
1 FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY \U0001f602
2           HUGGING_FACE \U0001f917
3           PARTY_POPPER \U0001f389
```

For a single emoji this code works:

```
data$text <- gsub("FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY", "\U0001f602", data$text)
```

the result is:

```
                              text
1 blabla HUGGING_FACE PARTY_POPPER
2    bla \U0001f602 bla \U0001f602
3                     PARTY_POPPER
```

However, I want to replace the other emoji names as well. The result should be:

```
                           text
1  blabla \U0001f917 \U0001f389
2 bla \U0001f602 bla \U0001f602
3                    \U0001f389
```

As there are thousands of emojis, I need something like:

```
data$text <- gsub(emojis$name, emojis$emoji, data$text)
```

This doesn't work (error: "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used numeric ") and I couldn't find a solution myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note in particular that minimal but complete reproducible code and input (using `dput`) are needed.  No one can run this code as  the input is missing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me now – I've edited the question and hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) gsubfn** Create a dictionary, `dict`, consisting of a list whose names are the names to replace and whose values are the values to replace them with.  Then use `gsubfn` to perform replacements of strings of non-spaces, `"\\S+"`, using the dictionary.  `gsubfn` takes the same arguments as `gsub` except the second argument can be such a list (or certain other objects).

```
library(gsubfn)

dict <- with(emojis, setNames(as.list(emoji), name))
gsubfn("\\S+", dict, data$text)
## [1] "blabla  "  "bla  bla " ""
```

**2) Base R** This uses `Reduce` to iterate through the rows of `emojis` replacing them one by one.

```
gsub_ <- function(s, i) with(emojis[i, ], gsub(name, emoji, s))
Reduce(gsub_, init = data$text, 1:nrow(emojis))
## [1] "blabla  "  "bla  bla " ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `mapvalues` in package `plyr`. Example:

```
library(plyr)

# data
data <- data.frame("ID" = 1:5, "text" = c("FACE_WITH_TEARS", "FACE_WITH_JOY",
                      "FACE_WITH_JOY", "FACE_WITH_PLAIN", "FACE_WITH_TEARS"))

# "dictionary" 
emojis <- data.frame("name" = c("FACE_WITH_TEARS", "FACE_WITH_JOY", "FACE_WITH_PLAIN"),
                     "emojis" = c("CRY", "HAPPY", "NUETRAL"))

data$text <- mapvalues(data$text, emojis$name, emojis$emojis)

data
```

The result is

```
  ID    text
1  1     CRY
2  2   HAPPY
3  3   HAPPY
4  4 NUETRAL
5  5     CRY
```

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to only work when there is no text around the emoji name. It does, e.g., replace "PARTY_POPPER" with "\U0001f389" but not "blabla PARTY_POPPER" with "blabla \U0001f389". Sorry that I haven't made my question clearer. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `stringr::str_replace_all` with [`setNames`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/setNames) to create a dictionary out of your `emojis` dataframe:

```r
data <- structure(list(text = c("blabla HUGGING_FACE PARTY_POPPER", "bla FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY bla FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY", "PARTY_POPPER")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
emojis <- structure(list(name = c("FACE_WITH_TEARS_OF_JOY", "HUGGING_FACE", 
                                  "PARTY_POPPER"), emoji = c("\U0001f602", "\U0001f917", "\U0001f389"
                                  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(stringr)
stringr::str_replace_all(data$text, setNames(emojis$emoji, emojis$name))
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/h8c89d).

Output:

```
[1] "blabla  "  "bla  bla " ""
```

Comment: Thanks as well. Different from your test case, in my dataset str_replace_all only works for cases without text around the emoji name. It does, e.g., replace "PARTY_POPPER" with "\U0001f389" but not "blabla PARTY_POPPER" with "blabla \U0001f389". Sorry that I haven't made my question clearer. I've edited it now and provided a reproducible data set.

Comment: @just_asking Use the updated code.